# convertir imagen en formato pgm en blanco y negro usando un textreader y un binary reader en C#

Tags: c#, imagen, binario

tengo una imagen en **formato PGM** que quiero editar a blanco y negro en **C#** y guardarla como una imagen nueva. He probado de todo ya y la verdad que no se que mas hacer, el tema es que tengo que usar si o si un **Binaryreader** y un **Textreader**. si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradezco muchisimo.

```
       using System;
       using System.IO;

       class Program
        {
       static void Main()
       {
        try
        {
            string inputImagePath = 
         @"C:\Users\uig45939\Desktop\continental_vdo_pp_dtco_4.0.pgm";
            string outputImagePath = @"C:\Users\uig45939\Desktop\schwarz- 
         weiss.pgm";

            using (TextReader headReader = new 
            StreamReader(inputImagePath))
            using (StreamWriter headWriter = new 
            StreamWriter(outputImagePath))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    string headerLine = headReader.ReadLine();
                    headWriter.WriteLine(headerLine);
                    Console.WriteLine(headerLine);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Schwarz-Weiß Bild erfolgreich erstellt!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error " + e.ToString());
           }
       }
       }
```

Esto es lo que tengo por ahora que me copia el Header de la antigua imagen.
Ahora me faltaria solamente poder cambiar los pixeles de la imagen con el binaryreader.

Aparte he intentado este methodo pero no da resultado ya que me borra el header de la nueva imagen y no me deja abrirla. Basicamente quiero cambiar la imagen de color a blanco y negro usando el binaryreader y cambiando asi los colores de la imagen, he buscado informacion en todos lados pero no he sido capaz de hacerlo, espero que alguien que tenga conocimiento sobre ello me pueda ayudar.

```
     using System;
     using System.IO;

     class Program
     {
     static void Main()
     {
        try
        {
            string inputImagePath = 
            @"C:\Users\uig45939\Desktop\continental_vdo_pp_dtco_4.0.pgm";
            string outputImagePath = @"C:\Users\uig45939\Desktop\schwarz- 
            weiss.pgm";

            using (BinaryReader imageReader = new 
            BinaryReader(File.Open(inputImagePath, FileMode.Open)))
            using (BinaryWriter imageWriter = new 
            BinaryWriter(File.Open(outputImagePath, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                

                while (true)
                {
                    byte currentByte = imageReader.ReadByte();
                    imageWriter.Write(currentByte);
                    if (currentByte == 10)  
                    {
                        string headerLine = ReadHeaderLine(imageReader);
                        imageWriter.Write(headerLine);
                        if (headerLine.StartsWith("255"))
                            break; 
                    }
                }

                
                while (imageReader.BaseStream.Position < 
                imageReader.BaseStream.Length)
                {
                    byte pixelValue = imageReader.ReadByte();
                    byte invertedValue = (byte)(255 - pixelValue);
                    imageWriter.Write(invertedValue);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Imagen en Schwarz-Weiss creada con 
          éxito!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }

    static string ReadHeaderLine(BinaryReader reader)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
    while (true)
    {
        byte currentByte = reader.ReadByte();
        Array.Resize(ref bytes, bytes.Length + 1);
        bytes[bytes.Length - 1] = currentByte;
        if (currentByte == 10)
            break;
    }
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
}
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que fue lo que probaste?? que fallo??? muestranos eso asi podemos guiarte con tus problemas...

Comment: muchas gracias por el comentario, la verdad que soy nuevo y no me entero mucho aun.. pues basicamente quiero editar una imagen a color a blanco y negro usando el binaryreader y el  textreader ya que no puedo usar ninguna biblioteca ni nada..

Comment: Pero que fue lo que probaste?? porque ese codigo basicamente no hace nada... que cosas intentaste que fallaron?

Comment: pues lo siento si no se me entiende... basicamente estoy abriendo la imagen con el notepad++ con el codigo que puse arriba estoy copiando el header de la imagen. ahora necesito con el binaryreader poder formatear cada byte de la imagen para poder ponerlo en blanco y negro. no puedo usar otra biblioteca.. espero haberme explicado mejor ahora y muchas gracias por la paciencia

Comment: "He probado de todo ya y la verdad que no se que mas hacer," como que??? yo no soy experto en el tema de cambio de colores... pero si decis que probaste de todo, tenes que mostrarlo.. Tene en cuenta que aca solucionamos problemas, no hacemos las cosas por otros...

Comment: que simpatico eres de verdad con tus comentarios, entre aqui pensando que alguien me podria ayudar pero ponerse asi con un usuario nuevo o directamente con una persona que quizas le cueste explicarse no lo veo muy profesional de tu parte... quizas me falten las palabras o lo haya explicado mal nose, pero creo que tus formas tampoco son las mas adecuadas y menos para un moderador.. pero bueno muchas gracias igualmente!!

Comment: ya intentaste lo de este [link](https://csharp.agrimetsoft.com/exercises/Image_Black_White)?, adicional gbianchi a lo que se refiere es a que nos proporciones ejemplos de lo que ya hiciste, para evitar comentarios como el mio con soluciones que ya probaste y no te funcionaron.

Comment: Genial!!! ahora si, alguien te va a poder ayudar!

Comment: Entiendo que quieres pasar de escala de grises a blanco y negro (2 colores solamente). Estuve leyendo y hay 2 formatos de PGM (ASCII y binary) tu necesitas las 2 formas o una en particular??? Por último, ayudaría que subieras una imagen de ejemplo